# Why is the control count decreased if a form is closed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a panel which displays `Form` objects. When the `Close()` method is called on a form, the `panel.Controls.Count` is modified, the Count is one less. How is this possible?

This is the way I show a form in th panel:

```
// insertForm is a windows form

insertForm.TopLevel = false;
insertForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
insertForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

this.pnlContent.Controls.Clear();
this.pnlContent.Controls.Add(insertForm);
```

And when somewhere `form.Close()` is called, the `Controls` count of `pnlContent` is 0. So, how is this possible? What all happens when `Close()` is called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Closing a form causes the form to be disposed, which in turn causes it to be removed from its parent's control-collection.

If you use a decompiler, you will notice two things:

1. When you add a control to a `ControlCollection`, the control's owner is set as the `ControlCollection's` owner.  `ControlCollection.Add(Control value)` calls  `value.AssignParent(this.owner)`.
2. When a control is disposed, it removes itself from its owner's `ControlCollection`.  Essentially, `Control.Dispose` calls `parent.Controls.Remove(this)`.

Lesson learned: **Don't use a ControlCollection  as general purpose collection-type for Controls.**   It is deeply integrated into WinForms for control-containment and parent-child relationships. Use this type only when you genuinely require a parent control to *contain* a child control.

Comment: Thanks. That explains a lot. So you suggest to create a custom panel with an own List of controls and to use this list instead of using the `Controls` property? Or what do you suggest in my situation (see startpost) and why?

Answer (score 1):

When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are closed and the form is disposed

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx

Comment: But the object is still 'alive'. I can still access properties. So why is it removed from the control collection?

Comment: It's true. But at code time, doesn't make sense you access your property of your object that you close before, right? You can access the properties because at code time, the compiler don't know if you close the form. But when you run the code, after the close, your panel controls count, for example, will be 0.

Answer (score 1):

The Controls collection performs two important jobs.  First it keeps track of the child controls of a container.  The order of the control objects in the collection determines their Z-order.  Secondly, it takes care of ensuring that controls are disposed when their parent is destroyed.  Which is the reason that you don't have to dispose controls yourself like you often need to do with other .NET classes that implement IDisposable.

Which leads to a nasty bug in your code, the Controls.Clear() method just removes controls from the collection, it does not dispose them.  That a very bad leak that will make your program fat and slow, eventually causing it to crash when Windows refuse to give it any more window handles.  You'll need to write it like this:

```
while (this.pnlContent.Controls.Count > 0) this.pnlContent.Controls[0].Dispose();
```

Which now also makes it obvious why the control count goes down when you call the Close() method, that disposes the form object which automatically removes it from its container's Control collection.

Disposing a control just destroys the native Windows operating system resources used by the control.  The Handle property being the most obvious one.  It does not otherwise make the .NET object disappear, that requires the garbage collector to run.  Keeping a reference to a disposed control is a bad idea, the GC won't destroy it as long as there's a reference to it and you're apt to get an ObjectDisposedException when you try to use it anyway.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. How do you know all these kind of things? You always amaze me with how much you know about winforms..